# wxPython autocomplete

Tags: python, ide, editor, autocomplete, wxpython

What editors or IDEs offer **decent** autocompletion for wxPython on Windows or Linux? Are there any? I tried several and support is either non-existant or limited.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse+PyDev with the install directory for wxPython added to the PythonPath has fully functioning autocomplete.
[Pydev](http://pydev.sourceforge.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I use [Ulipad](http://ulipad.googlecode.com), and its has good autocompletion for wxPython too.

Answer (score 1):

[Wingide](http://www.wingware.com/pub/wingide/wingware_brochure.pdf) can do it

Answer (score 1):

I use Eclipse/PyDev for wxPython development. I've been very satisfied with Eclipse for Python development productivity. It does have support for autocompletion for wxPython.

Answer (score 1):

I'm partial to PyCharm. However, most IDEs will auto complete code based on what modules you've imported, so it's not specific to PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the default windows IDE for Python is can autocomplete, with code not from the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text + [anaconda](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda)

I'm coding in a small project using wxPython, it provides good autocompletion function for the wxPython.

Answer (score -1):

try use *brain* to autocomplete... :)

just joking. when I coding in in PyQt4, I open qt-assistant and search the manual,
and wrap myclass like : MyButton = QPusuButton

I think it is impossible to use autocomplete in python,
because only in runtime the computer know what happens.

Comment: It's definitely not impossible. NetBeans, Eclipse with PyDev, and Komodo Edit do a good job at autocompletion within the standard library.

Comment: It's not impossible but definitely harder than usual. By indexing the modules and some smart guessing some IDEs come close. For example as soon as you use an object with some methods the IDE can start guessing what type that object might be and give you reasonable options. My IDE can actually do autocompletion in PyQt4.